# Raspbian Eclipse JDK11 memory

Tags: linux, eclipse, java-8, raspbian, java-11

Hello and sorry for my english.
I'm trying to use Eclipse in Raspbian and I have installed OpenjJDK 11.0.7; when I execute Eclipse I'm having this problem:

`OpenJDK Server VM warning: Ignoring option MaxPermSize; support was removed in 8.0`

I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: In the `eclipse.ini` remove the line starting with `-XX:MaxPermSize=`. But as far as I know, this line does not exist in the current Eclipse version. Are you sure your Eclipse is up-to-date?

Comment: It's only a warning, so it shouldn't actually harm, does it?